# jQuery Sliding Questionnaire

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

I am interested in doing a questionnaire with 5 questions.  Each Question would be in a single view/page ( from users' perspective ).
The questions will have 2 to 7 answers in each page.
I want each question to be a single Button.
As each button is clicked, the page would scroll to the next page/Question.
I would like to transition to slide to the right.
I want to record the answer for each button, so that I can create a query at the last stage.

Bonus:  I would like there to be a button that will go to the last page.

I Know JavaScript fairly well, But I am not sure how to start something like this. Does anyone have some sample code.  Is there a jQuery library I should be looking at?
any other suggestions.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to load all the questions into the same HTML page and make each 'slide' a div that fills the width & height of the browser window.

Each 'next' button simply points to the next div and you can link directly to the final slide.

You can use jQuery's AJAX functionality to save the data as you go if that's what you're after, or just save the whole lot in one go at the end.

And you'll need the jQuery [localScroll](http://flesler.blogspot.co.uk/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html) and [scrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.co.uk/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) plugins

Comment: what if I want a Button that will goto the very first node?